# Curve with different scale streched

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, scale

I'm new to 3D modeling and I have an issue when trying to apply modifier Curve to Mesh when it is scaled.

As you can see in the below gif, I create a new BezierCircle and a Cube. If I apply modifier Curve to cube using as object the BezierCircle it works.

But if i scale up BezierCircle and Cube (applying the scale using ctrl+A) and reapply Curve modifier the mesh Cube become deforms and streched.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Each curve vertex has a radius. When you scale your curve in *Object* mode, the radius doesn't change, but if you apply the scale, the radius will change to the curve object scale before applying, and it will affect the objects that are parented to the curve, like your cube.

You can check the vertices radius in the *N panel > Item > Radius* (or *Mean Radius* if you've selected several vertices). You can bring back the value to 1. You can also right click *(Contexte Menu)* > *Set Curve Radius*, type the value you want and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can also uncheck *Radius* in the curve properties panel :).

Comment: yes, I just wanted to give the shortest ways  ;)

Comment: Now it's all very clear. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Add a default cube,set the x scale to 0.629
- Add an array modifier with "count" set to 5
- Add a default Bezier Circle
- Add a curve modifier to the cube, set to the Bezier Circle
- You should see a perfect pentagon:
  [image]
- Reduce the Y scale and observe the pentagon hollows out:
  [image]
- Increase the Y scale past 1 and observe the center of the pentagon begins to overlap and visual artifacts appear because the geometry is non-manifold (i.e., there are now overlapping and intersecting faces)
  [image]